# PHP, use of date function

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-services

I have a problem with the date function in PHP. i cannot figure out how to use it properly. I have never learnt PHP and I cannot find a way to either. I just need to know how the date function works properly. When I try to add the date into a database the query does not work. I have use mySql as well as php in my project and want to despite the risk of cracker since I am not publishing anything. I am just a student doing a project and we do not have any IT teachers at our school. Your help will be appreciated.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");

if($type == 'borrow')

    $query="UPDATE books set Availablity = ".$zero." where ID=".$id."";
    mysql_query($query) or die (" borrow operation failed due to query 1");
    $query1="INSERT into borrowed (BookID, BookName, BorrowedID, BorrowedName,
    DateBorrowed, Extended, Returned) values('".$id."','".$bkName."','".$userid."'
    ,'".$userName."',".$date."','".$zero."','".$zero.")";
    mysql_query($query1) or die (" borrow operation failed to due query 2");
    echo "borrow begun";
```

Comment: what is the erro your getting?

Comment: Use built in functions in SQL to do that. Set columns/fields to DATE for Year/Month/Day or DATETIME for Year/Month/Day and Hour/Min/sec. Read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html - the value in the SQL query is NOW() which takes the current time. Read more about it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Comment: hi @Thirumalaimurugan, It fails when running query 1, it dies.

Comment: @kexxcream I am using php

Comment: what is the $id check the $query by echo that

Comment: i get that from the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made corrections. Use this,

```
$query1="INSERT into borrowed (BookID, BookName, BorrowedID, BorrowedName,
    DateBorrowed, Extended, Returned) values('".$id."','".$bkName."','".$userid."','".$userName."','".$date."','".$zero."','".$zero.")";
```

Make sure DateBorrowed have type Date or DateTime.

Comment: hi there, I attempted the fix you suggested, i still get the same error. It fails when running query 1, it dies

Comment: $query1="INSERT into borrowed (BookID, BookName, BorrowedID, BorrowedName,
    DateBorrowed, Extended, Returned) values('".$id."','".$bkName."','".$userid."','".$userName."','".$date."','".$zero."','".$zero."')"; Try this

Comment: Will you try to post your complete post. Because i can't find from where you are getting that id. So, It would be better if u post the complete code.

Comment: If BookID is primary key then remove it from query.
$query1="INSERT into borrowed (BookName, BorrowedID, BorrowedName,
    DateBorrowed, Extended, Returned) values('".$bkName."','".$userid."','".$userName."','".$date."','".$zero."','".$zero."')";

Comment: i used the echo function to print the date that will enter the database and it comes out as null, so that is where the error is

Comment: thanks a lot, it was just a syntax error, you comments made me review it all and it worked out :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need current date in mysql db, try use current timestamp as column type instead of using php function. Here some links that i found about how to do it

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: i used the date format in my database, YYYY-MM-DD and that is as a column

Comment: date type will not automatically fill with current timestamp. just change time of this collum: "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Answer (score 0):

First of all you make sure that u have made the modification in MySQL table ***borrowed***.
Modification: Change the **DateBorrowed** type to **TIMESTAMP**. And after that you follow the below code as reference.

```
if($type == 'borrow')
{
    $query="UPDATE books set Availablity = ".$zero." where ID=".$id."";
    mysql_query($query) or die (" borrow operation failed due to query 1");
    $query1="INSERT into borrowed (BookID, BookName, BorrowedID, BorrowedName,
    DateBorrowed, Extended, Returned) values('".$id."','".$bkName."','".$userid."'
    ,'".$userName."',now()','".$zero."','".$zero.")";
    mysql_query($query1) or die (" borrow operation failed to due query 2");
    echo "borrow begun";
}
```

After this you don't have to worry about date function. BTW the date function format is correct. Hence, the error resides somewhere inside your query only. And this type of error occurs only when you have not properly configured your database table. So, I suggest you to recheck with your table structure.